# d3js force layout set node symbol based on d

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a force layout where nodes will have different images (icons) based on some condition in the .data().  I can understand that we can set other attributes such as style, class etc easily following the standard approach:

```
nodeSelction.data(...)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return xxx; })
```

Is it possible to do the same thing for deciding whether to add a svg:circle, or some image icon?  I tried doing the same thing to append method, but it doesn't take a function. That is,
the following snippet doesn't work.

```
nodeSelction.data(...)
  .enter()
  .append(function(d) { return d.group==0?"circle" : "usr.png"})
  .attr("class", function { return xxx; })
```

So, what is the correct way to achieve the above?

Comment: May be you can add images to data and use it render the image something like this http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/n28k7oqo/3/

Comment: Thanks, it works!